# How to use non-atomic functions on cvxpy variable?

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, cvxpy, qutip

Consider the scenario where I define a CVXPY variable, a 4x4 semidefinite matrix, as below

`x = cvxpy.Semidef(4)`

If I want to write a constraint involving the trace of this, it seems I must use the atomic function

`cvxpy.atoms.affine.trace.trace(x)`

I would like to enforce a specific constraint on `x`, namely that it has a positive partial transpose. There is no atomic function like the trace in this case but such a method has already been written (see http://qutip.org/docs/3.1.0/modules/qutip/partial_transpose.html#partial_transpose). Can I get CVXPY to allow me to write a constraint in terms of these non-atomic functions that already exist elsewhere (e.g. numpy, qutip and so on)?

Thanks!

Comment: If your question is: can i use numpy / any other function on my cvxpy data-structures? The answer is no: cvxpy is based on it's DCP rules and those are only available for those [functions implemented](https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/functions/index.html#). "black-box" usage is impossible.

Comment: @sascha I see. In this sense, is it the case that MATLAB allows this but not Python? Or are there any CVX solvers in Python that allow blackbox implementation of functions on CVX varibles?

Comment: Matlab has no knowledge of DCP rules. Either cvx (the matlab equivalent and original implementation before cvxpy) supports other functions or there is some other flaw. DCP-based approaches can't work with black-boxes. These are methods by construction to beat the (in general) NP-hard task of proving convexity. Try to mimic the code you refer to with cvxpy's functions. There are a lot of those available (mimicking numpy's).

Comment: Ah I see. It looks like the partial transpose function (which is linear so is convex) I used in MATLAB is explicitly compatible with CVX but the one I linked is not.